# Which collection best suits this

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I have 100's of employee objects. Employee object has name, age, salary. I should retrieve an employee or employees with specific name at some point.

I'm just thinking

```
HashMap<String, List>
```

name in to the key, all objects in to the list.

I know map is not a collection :P

Any idea of a best collection instead of a map. to retrieve at any time.

Comment: What is the problem with HashMap?

Comment: do you have Perons with same name? are you allowed to do some trick on their names?

Answer (score 2):

You should first create `Employee` class with all relevant fields (name, age, salary etc)
Then you can use `HashMap`:

```
 Map<String, Employee> map = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `List<Employee>` and you want to filter the list by the name or age etc I guess [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) is good for this purpose.

Here is an example, say you want to filter all employee by their name:

```
HasArgumentWithValue<Employee, String> matcher = Lambda.having(Lambda.on(Employee.class).getName(), Matchers.equalTo(name));
List<Employee> filteredEmployess = Lambda.filter(matcher, allEmployess);
```

By static import the above code would be:

```
List<Employee> filteredEmployess = filter(having(on(Employee.class).getName(), equalTo(name)), employees);
```

You can find more example [here](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures)

For age it would be usefull to find employees having age greater than 30:

```
HasArgumentWithValue<Employee, Integer> matcher = Lambda.having(Lambda.on(Employee.class).getAge(), Matchers.greaterThan(30))
```

Answer (score 0):

Though **Map** doesn't extend **Collection** class; but still Map is a type of Collection. So if your purpose is served by **HashMap**; then will suggest go for it.

```
 HashMap<String, Employee> map = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
```

Comment: Rai. I just wanna know how this can be acheived by way of collection. not map.

Comment: If you want to retrieve Employees using their name; then go for HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why HashMap doesn't suit your needs, but if you want to be able to iterate all employees (as if it was a collection), you can still use:

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Employee>>();

// populate your map

for (List<Employee> list : map.values()) {
  for (Employee employee : list) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I should retrieve an employee **or employees** with **specific name** at some
>   point.

from the line above, I thought you have multiple employees with same name. If this is the case, I suggest guava's **Multimap**. e.g. [HashMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html)

Comment: Thanks. I have persons with same name !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the name attribute in the **Employee** class as the key make sure you don't have employees with the same name. The map uses a key, in your case a String, and each key has to be unique. If they are you're fine with HashMap<**String** name, Employee>.

(create the **Employee** class with all attributes)

However if they're not unique, many employee can have the same name, you should consider adding a attribute to the **Employee** class. Something like

```
private int ID;
```

and use it as key like this:

```
HashMap<int, Employee>
```

HashMap is very good in time complexity. In average a *get()* call would get the time T(n) = O(1) (i.e. in constant time). Same goes for a *put* call.